# Wondering how to filter a list using another list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to code and am presented with a problem I don't really know how to face. In my code.org assignment, I'm required to filter songs by an artist. A have code that chooses 1 random artists from a data set of artists. And now by using that one filtered artist in a list, I have to get songs from the same data set that are by that artist,

```js
function artistPicker() {
  var index;
  filteredArtist = [];
  filteredSongName = [];
  index = randomNumber(0, artistData.length - 1);
  var artistName = artistData[index];
  appendItem(filteredArtist, artistName);
  for (var i = 0; i < artistData.length; i++) {
    if (songNameData[i] == filteredArtist) {
      appendItem(filteredSongName, songNameData[i]);
    }
  }
  setScreen("displayScreen");
  setText("textOutput", artistName + filteredSongName);
}
```

this is what i have so far. It picks a random artist but doesnt filter out songs by the selected artist.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have data like

```js
const data = [
 {artist: 'my band', song: 'my song'}, 
 {artist: 'my band', song: 'my other song'},
 {artist: 'your band', song: 'your song'}
]
```

then you can select a random artist and filter the list by that artist:

```js
const randomIx = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)
const artist = data[randomIx].artist
const allArtistEntries = data.filter(entry => entry.artist === artist)
const artistSongTitles = allArtistEntries.map(entry => entry.song)
```